# if statement inside a for statement runs only once in R

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I have a dataframe which contains the following text:

```
df$Position 

[1] "START"  "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "START"  "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "START"  "START"  "START"  "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "START"
```

[22] "START"  "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "START"  "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "START"  "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE"
[43] "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE"

I would like to replace the "MIDDLE" text before the previous "START" text with "END" to mark the correct position.

So i am basically iterating through the positions in the frame and if the condition is met then replace the text.

```
for(i in 2:i)
{    
# iterate through the frame
if (df$Position[i]=="START" && df$Position[i-1]=="MIDDLE")

{
df$Position[i-1] <- "END"
}
}
```

This appears to work once only. I end up with the following output:

```
[1] "START"  "MIDDLE" "END"    "START"  "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "START"  "START"  "START"  "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "START"
```

[22] "START"  "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "START"  "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "START"  "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE"
[43] "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE"

I'm wondering what i am doing wrong here and if there is a better approach (maybe a custom function??) to complete this task.

Regards
Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question will likely cause a bit of nail biting to most SO users, because to nail it (no pun intended) requires some clever index manipulation in R.

You can solve the problem by recognizing that whenever `MIDDLE` occurs in a position *before* `START` occurs, you should replace that value with `END`.  Hence, you can find all occurrences of `MIDDLE`, and then match that against a vector containing all occurrences of `START` offset by one to the left.

```
x <- position == "MIDDLE"
y <- c((position == "START")[2:length(position)], FALSE)
position[x & y] <- "END"

> position
 [1] "START"  "MIDDLE" "END"    "START"  "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE"
 [9] "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "END"    "START"  "START" 
[17] "START"  "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE" "END"    "START"  "START"  "MIDDLE" "MIDDLE"
[25] "MIDDLE"
```

**Data:**

```
position <- c("START", "MIDDLE", "MIDDLE", "START", "MIDDLE", "MIDDLE", "MIDDLE",
              "MIDDLE", "MIDDLE", "MIDDLE" ,"MIDDLE", "MIDDLE", "MIDDLE", "MIDDLE",
              "START", "START", "START" , "MIDDLE", "MIDDLE", "MIDDLE", "START",
              "START", "MIDDLE", "MIDDLE", "MIDDLE")
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Tim, your code worked a treat. Best Regards Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

Try `for (i in 2:length(df$Position))` instead of `for(i in 2:i)`.